# Understanding Numpy internals for profiling purposes

Tags: numpy, profiling

Profiling a piece of numpy code shows that I'm spending most of the time within these two functions

```
numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py.__getitem__:301
numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py.__array_finalize__:279
```

Here's the Numpy source:

- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L301
- https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py#L279

**Question #1:**

`__getitem__` seems to be called every time I'm using something like `my_array[arg]` and it's getting more expensive if `arg` is not an integer but a slice. Is there any way to speed up calls to array slices?

E.g. in

```
for i in range(idx): res[i] = my_array[i:i+10].mean()
```

**Question #2:**

When exactly does `__array_finalize__` get called and how can I speed up by reducing the number of calls to this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could not use matrices as much and just use 2d numpy arrays.  I typically only use matrices for a short-time to take advantage of the syntax for multiplication (but with the addition of the .dot method on arrays, I find I do that less and less as well).

But, to your questions:

1) There really is no short-cut to `__getitem__` unless defmatrix over-rides `__getslice__` which it could do but doesn't yet.   There are the .item and .itemset methods which are optimized for integer getting and setting (and return Python objects rather than NumPy's array-scalars)

2) `__array_finalize__` is called whenever an array object (or a subclass) is created.  It is called from the C-function that every array-creation gets funneled through.  https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/ctors.c#L1003

In the case of sub-classes defined purely in Python, it is calling back into the Python interpreter from C which has overhead.  If the matrix class were a builtin type (a Cython-based cdef class, for example), then the call could avoid the Python interpreter overhead.

Comment: Good to see you on SO, welcome! So, does it mean that some of the questions on the numpy user list will forward to SO?

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, Travis! Switching to 2D-arrays was really easy and a good way to get rid of those unnecessary calls.

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1:**

Since array slices can sometimes require a copy of the underlying data structure (holding the pointers to the data in memory) they can be quite expensive. If you're really bottlenecked by this in your above example, you can perform mean operations by actually iterating over the i to i+10 elements and manually creating the mean. For some operations this won't give any performance improvement, but avoiding creating new data structures will generally speed up the process.

Another note, if you're not using native types inside numpy you will get a Very large performance penalty to manipulating a numpy array. Say you're array has dtype=float64 and your native machine float size is float32 -- this will cost a lot of extra computation power for numpy and performance overall will drop. Sometimes this is fine and you can just take the hit for maintaining a data type. Other times it's arbitrary what type the float or int is stored as internally. In these cases try dtype=float instead of dtype=float64. Numpy should default to your native type. I've had 3x+ speedups on numpy intensive algorithms by making this change.

**Question 2:**

`__array_finalize__` "is called whenever the system internally allocates a new array from obj, where obj is a subclass (subtype) of the (big)ndarray" according to [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/Subclasses). Thus this is a result described in the first question. When you slice and make a new array, you have to finalize that array by either making structural copies or wrapping the original structure. This operation takes time. Avoiding slices will save on this operation, though for multidimensional data it may be impossible to completely avoid calls to `__array_finalize__`.

Comment: Thank you, Pyrce, sticking to a fixed type (float32 is totally ok) is a good idea, too!